# Is it bad behavior to edit and answer a question?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, best-practices

From time to time I notice questions that could be improved (in style, punctuation, clarity of thought, tags, etc.) But I also have the answer to them.

I just feel wrong editing a question (even for a retag) that I also answer.

What's the policy on this?

Comment: I've done it - it cleans-up the site :)

Comment: We now have badges that actually encourage this. Explainer, Refiner, and Illuminator are awarded for editing and answering questions, provided that the answer has a positive score and the edit and answer occurred within 12 hours of each other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do it.

You're helping the site, the readers and the whole shack when you edit a badly written or unclear post into a well written/unambiguous version. Even if that means realigning it with more appropriate tags.

Just because you want to answer as well doesn't mean there's any kind of conflict of interest or any social no-no frowning at you for answering a question you just happen to improve.

Comment: +1 - for you editing and answering this question.

Comment: +1 - for *eating your own dog food*